# How can I add an order item to an existing shipment programmatically in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am creating a shipment in Magento from an import file that reads the order items to be shipped line by line, but after I create the shipment and add the first item I'm running into difficulty. I am creating the shipment like this:

```
$itemsData = array(
    'qtys' => array(
        $orderItem->getId() => $importData['qty placed'],
    )
);
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)
    ->prepareShipment($itemsData['qtys']);
$shipment->addComment("Shipment created from shipment importer", false);
$shipment->register();
$shipment->getOrder()
    ->setIsInProcess(true);
$shipment->setShippingCost($shipCost);
if (isset($trackingNumber)) {
    $this->addTrack($shipment, $importData); //this function adds the tracking data
}
if ($order->getCustomerEmail()) {
    $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
    $shipment->sendEmail(true, '');
}
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($shipment)
    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder());
$transactionSave->save();
$shipment->save();
```

Which works great for the first item but for shipments with multiple items I am unable to add the next item to the shipment. I am trying to add subsequent items like this:

```
//I first load the existing shipment
$shipItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_item');
$shipItem->setShipment($shipment);
$shipItem->setOrderItem($orderItem);
$shipItem->setQty($qtyShipped);
$shipItem->register();

$shipment->addItem($shipItem);
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($shipment)
    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder());
$transactionSave->save();
$shipment->save();
```

Now in the Order View / Information page in admin, the second item still says 'invoiced' and not 'shipped', when I click the Shipments tab the total quantity is listed as '1' instead of 2, however when I click on that shipment to view the details, both items are listed. So it seems like it is kinda working, but not really

Not all items will ship so I can't just load the order and mark them all as shipped.
Any ideas on how I can make this work? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what the `sales/service_order` is for, normally you use `sales/order`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. After reading around on stackoverflow and Magento forums I have found out that the shipment api should support shipments of single items. However, it seems that your code just does not support this.

Maybe I would be best to try using the shipment API of Magento?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/sales_order_shipment

Answer (score 0):

Get your existing shipment model from the order

```
        $mageShipColl = $mageOrder->getShipmentsCollection();
        $mageShipment = $mageShipColl->getFirstItem();
        $mageShipment->setOrder($mageOrder)
            ->setStoreId($mageOrder->getStoreId())
            ->setCustomerId($mageOrder->getCustomerId())
            ->setBillingAddressId($mageOrder->getBillingAddressId())
            ->setShippingAddressId($mageOrder->getShippingAddressId());
        Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset('sales_convert_order', 'to_shipment', $mageOrder, $mageShipment);
```

Now do this:

```
$mageShipmentItem = $convertor->itemToShipmentItem($mageOrderItem);
$mageShipmentItem->setQty($qty_you_shipped);
//register shipment item for existing shipment only
if($mageShipment->getId()) {
  $mageShipmentItem->register();
}
$mageShipment->addItem($mageShipmentItem);

        $mageTrack = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track');
        try {
            $mageTrack->setData('carrier_code', $carrier)
                ->setData('number', $trackNo)
                ->setData('title', $carrierTitle);

            $comment = "Shipped via $carrier with tracking# $trackNo. Emailed confirmation to $shipToEmail.";

            $mageShipment->addTrack($mageTrack);
            //Do not register an existing shipment
            if(!$mageShipment->getId()) {
                $mageShipment->register();
            }
            $mageShipment->addComment($comment, $shouldNotifyCust);

            //this may or may not be needed
            $mageShipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

            $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                ->addObject($mageShipment)
                ->addObject($mageShipment->getOrder())
                ->save();

            //email customer only if order is complete
            if($mageOrder->getStatus() == "complete") {
                $mageShipment->sendEmail(true, (($this->includeCommentInCustomerEmail) ? $comment : ''));
                $mageShipment->setEmailSent(true);
            }

            $mageShipment->save();


        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $errMsg = "Error saving shipment: " . $e->getMessage();
            Mage::log($errMsg, null, $logPath);
        }
```

Comment: Also you may want to adhere to @FabianBlechschmidt's comment.